# How can I sort my posts by "Last Time Edited"?

Tags: support, questions, answers, search

I got my second Yearling badge a few weeks ago. I've learned a lot about RPGs during my time here, I've also learned a lot about the StackExchange culture, which took a good bit of time to get a grasp of. My English is still pretty bad, but it has also improved significantly.

Thanks for the help, guys! I wouldn't be able to get better without your help, your advice on how to do stuff, your reminders about the rules, etc. RPG.SE has the most friendly culture I have seen.

So, I believe that it's now the time for me to go through my old questions and answers and edit/remove them if needed.

The problem is, while I can sort them by the date they were posted, I cannot distinguish those that were edited recently from those that stayed the way they are since the beginning. Eventually, I will probably go through all of my posts, but I am not 100% positive about that, and I want to focus on the oldest posts for now, the ones written in 2016 and not edited since then.

**So, how can I sort my posts, including both questions and answers, by the day they were last touched by me?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the search bar with [user:30214](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=user%3a30214) to find all posts from you. You can easily find this search entry by clicking on your profile - it automatically fills the search bar in the upper part of the site. After that you click on "active" in the row that shows on the left side the number of posts found (161 for you) and on the left the different sorting categories "relevance", "newest", "votes" and "active".

"active" will give you a list of most recently edited posts.

This will not necessarily give you posts touched by *you* though because the system doesn't care about *who* edited the post. This means that edits from other people will make a post appear further ahead in the results.

One thing though (emphasis mine):

> So, I believe that it's now the time for me to go through my old questions and answers and edit/**remove them if needed**.

I am not sure why you would want to remove your posts. Your old questions and answers may very well help people in the future that have a question you answered or that have the same question as you, so there wouldn't be a need to remove them.